# Http status 500 with error message "Error when processing resource" when creating Sales Order with SDK

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk, s4hana

The OData Service I used is API_SALES_ORDER_SRV in SAP API Business Hub.

The payload to create sales order is as below. It works very good in SAP Gateway Client.

```
{
  "DistributionChannel": "01",
  "OrganizationDivision": "01",
  "SalesOrderType": "***",
  "SalesOrganization": "***",
  "SoldToParty": "***",
  "to_Item": [
  {
    "SalesOrderItem" : "10",
    "RequestedQuantity": "10",
    "Material": "***"
  }
  ]
}
```

But when I create sales order with Cloud SDK, I got the following error message.

```
2019-11-12 19:51:02.870 ERROR 10392 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.b.h.service.MySalesOrderService        : The endpoint responded with HTTP error code 500.

Full error message: 
Error when processing resource

com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler$ErpODataException: The endpoint responded with HTTP error code 500.

Full error message: 
Error when processing resource
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createException(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:114)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:94)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:31)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.internal.ODataConnectivityUtil.checkHttpStatus(ODataConnectivityUtil.java:217)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.impl.ODataCreateRequestImpl.create(ODataCreateRequestImpl.java:275)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.impl.ODataCreateRequestImpl.handleExecute(ODataCreateRequestImpl.java:391)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.impl.ODataCreateRequestImpl.execute(ODataCreateRequestImpl.java:367)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperCreate.execute(FluentHelperCreate.java:155)
    at com.bosch.hackathon.service.MySalesOrderService.createSalesOrder(MySalesOrderService.java:451)
    at com.bosch.hackathon.controllers.MySalesOrderController.createSalesOrderSDK(MySalesOrderController.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.lambda$doFilter$1(RequestAccessorFilter.java:71)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.lambda$execute$0(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:317)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextCallable.call(ThreadContextCallable.java:247)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.execute(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:319)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.doFilter(RequestAccessorFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2019-11-12 19:51:02.888  WARN 10392 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [com.bosch.hackathon.exception.BusinessException: The endpoint responded with HTTP error code 500.

Full error message: 
Error when processing resource]
```

The code I used to create Sales order is as below. First I build an Sales Order Object and then use it as the parameter of method createSalesOrder.

```
private SalesOrder buildSalesOrderObject() {
    SalesOrderItem item = SalesOrderItem.builder()
                                         .salesOrderItem("myplant")
                                         .material("mymaterial")
                                         .requestedQuantity(new BigDecimal(10))
                                         .build();

    SalesOrder salesOrder = SalesOrder.builder()
                                       .salesOrderType("YTA")
                                       .salesOrganization("myso")
                                       .distributionChannel("01")
                                       .organizationDivision("01")
                                       .soldToParty("party")
                                       .item(item)
                                       .build();

    return salesOrder;
}

public SalesOrder createSalesOrder() throws BusinessException {

    SalesOrder salesOrderCreated = buildSalesOrderObject();
    try {
        salesOrderCreated = salesOrderService.createSalesOrder(salesOrder)
                                             .execute(DestinationUtil.getHttpDestinationT4X());
    } catch (ODataException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw BusinessException.convert(e);
    }

    return salesOrderCreated;
}
```

Could you take a look at this issue?

SAP Cloud SDK Version: 3.3.1

S/4HANA On-premise Version: 1909

Provide wire log.

```
2019-11-15 08:59:14.717 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection request: [route: {}->http://host:8091][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 100; total allocated: 0 of 200]
2019-11-15 08:59:14.731 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://host:8091][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 100; total allocated: 1 of 200]
2019-11-15 08:59:14.733 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Opening connection {}->http://host:8091
2019-11-15 08:59:14.944 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .i.c.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator : Connecting to host/ip1:8091
2019-11-15 08:59:15.161 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .i.c.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator : Connection established ip2:58702<->ip1:8091
2019-11-15 08:59:15.162 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Executing request GET /sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/$metadata HTTP/1.1
2019-11-15 08:59:15.162 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019-11-15 08:59:15.163 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> GET /sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/$metadata HTTP/1.1
2019-11-15 08:59:15.163 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.HttpClientWrapper$ApacheHttpHeader@65d86a53
2019-11-15 08:59:15.163 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Host: host:8091
2019-11-15 08:59:15.163 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2019-11-15 08:59:15.163 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/1.8.0_191)
2019-11-15 08:59:15.164 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2019-11-15 08:59:16.485 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2019-11-15 08:59:16.486 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << set-cookie: sap-usercontext=sap-client=011; path=/
2019-11-15 08:59:16.486 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << set-cookie: MYSAPSSO2=***; path=/; domain=***
2019-11-15 08:59:16.486 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << set-cookie: SAP_SESSIONID_***_011=***; path=/
2019-11-15 08:59:16.486 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << content-type: application/xml
2019-11-15 08:59:16.486 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << content-length: 8058
2019-11-15 08:59:16.486 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << last-modified: Mon, 21 Oct 2019 07:48:47 GMT
2019-11-15 08:59:16.486 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << cache-control: max-age=0
2019-11-15 08:59:16.486 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << dataserviceversion: 2.0
2019-11-15 08:59:16.486 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << sap-processing-info: ODataBEP=,crp=,RAL=,st=,MedCacheHub=Table,codeployed=X,softstate=
2019-11-15 08:59:16.486 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << sap-server: true
2019-11-15 08:59:16.486 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << sap-perf-fesrec: 893169.000000
2019-11-15 08:59:16.487 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << content-encoding: gzip
2019-11-15 08:59:16.492 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2019-11-15 08:59:16.496 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.h.c.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies  : Cookie accepted [sap-usercontext="sap-client=011", version:0, domain:host, path:/, expiry:null]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.497 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.h.c.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies  : Cookie accepted [MYSAPSSO2="***", version:0, domain:***, path:/, expiry:null]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.497 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.h.c.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies  : Cookie accepted [SAP_SESSIONID_***_011="***", version:0, domain:host, path:/, expiry:null]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.621 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://host:8091] can be kept alive indefinitely
2019-11-15 08:59:16.622 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
2019-11-15 08:59:16.622 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://host:8091][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 100; total allocated: 1 of 200]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.624 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : CookieSpec selected: default
2019-11-15 08:59:16.641 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : Cookie [version: 0][name: MYSAPSSO2][value: ***][domain: ***][path: /][expiry: null] match [host:8091/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.642 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : Cookie [version: 0][name: SAP_SESSIONID_***_011][value: ***][domain: host][path: /][expiry: null] match [host:8091/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.642 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : Cookie [version: 0][name: sap-usercontext][value: sap-client=011][domain: host][path: /][expiry: null] match [host:8091/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.642 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache   : Auth cache not set in the context
2019-11-15 08:59:16.642 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection request: [route: {}->http://host:8091][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 100; total allocated: 1 of 200]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.642 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://host:8091][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 100; total allocated: 1 of 200]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.643 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
2019-11-15 08:59:16.643 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Executing request HEAD /sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV HTTP/1.1
2019-11-15 08:59:16.643 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019-11-15 08:59:16.643 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> HEAD /sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV HTTP/1.1
2019-11-15 08:59:16.643 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> x-csrf-token: Fetch
2019-11-15 08:59:16.643 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.HttpClientWrapper$ApacheHttpHeader@54937cbe
2019-11-15 08:59:16.643 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Host: host:8091
2019-11-15 08:59:16.643 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2019-11-15 08:59:16.643 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/1.8.0_191)
2019-11-15 08:59:16.643 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Cookie: MYSAPSSO2=***; SAP_SESSIONID_***_011=***; sap-usercontext=sap-client=011
2019-11-15 08:59:16.643 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2019-11-15 08:59:16.902 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2019-11-15 08:59:16.903 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << content-type: text/html
2019-11-15 08:59:16.903 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << content-length: 0
2019-11-15 08:59:16.903 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << x-csrf-token: jgGDK5ILPjPZmMUDQJmvLg==
2019-11-15 08:59:16.903 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << dataserviceversion: 2.0
2019-11-15 08:59:16.903 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0
2019-11-15 08:59:16.903 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << pragma: no-cache
2019-11-15 08:59:16.903 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT
2019-11-15 08:59:16.903 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << sap-processing-info: ODataBEP=,crp=,RAL=,st=,MedCacheHub=,codeployed=,softstate=
2019-11-15 08:59:16.903 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << sap-server: true
2019-11-15 08:59:16.904 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << sap-perf-fesrec: 49848.000000
2019-11-15 08:59:16.904 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2019-11-15 08:59:16.904 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://host:8091] can be kept alive indefinitely
2019-11-15 08:59:16.904 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
2019-11-15 08:59:16.904 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://host:8091][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 100; total allocated: 1 of 200]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.924 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : CookieSpec selected: default
2019-11-15 08:59:16.924 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : Cookie [version: 0][name: MYSAPSSO2][value:***][domain: ***][path: /][expiry: null] match [host:8091/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrder]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.924 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : Cookie [version: 0][name: SAP_SESSIONID_***_011][value: ***][domain: host][path: /][expiry: null] match [host:8091/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrder]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.925 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : Cookie [version: 0][name: sap-usercontext][value: sap-client=011][domain: host][path: /][expiry: null] match [host:8091/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrder]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.925 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache   : Auth cache not set in the context
2019-11-15 08:59:16.925 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection request: [route: {}->http://host:8091][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 100; total allocated: 1 of 200]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.925 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://host:8091][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 100; total allocated: 1 of 200]
2019-11-15 08:59:16.925 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
2019-11-15 08:59:16.926 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Executing request POST /sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrder HTTP/1.1
2019-11-15 08:59:16.926 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019-11-15 08:59:16.926 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> POST /sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrder HTTP/1.1
2019-11-15 08:59:16.926 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> x-csrf-token: jgGDK5ILPjPZmMUDQJmvLg==
2019-11-15 08:59:16.926 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/json
2019-11-15 08:59:16.926 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Accept: application/json
2019-11-15 08:59:16.926 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.HttpClientWrapper$ApacheHttpHeader@f38e7be
2019-11-15 08:59:16.926 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 218
2019-11-15 08:59:16.926 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Host: host:8091
2019-11-15 08:59:16.926 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2019-11-15 08:59:16.926 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/1.8.0_191)
2019-11-15 08:59:16.926 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Cookie: MYSAPSSO2=***; SAP_SESSIONID_***_011=***; sap-usercontext=sap-client=011
2019-11-15 08:59:16.926 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2019-11-15 08:59:17.150 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
2019-11-15 08:59:17.150 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
2019-11-15 08:59:17.150 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << content-length: 30
2019-11-15 08:59:17.150 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << sap-processing-info: ODataBEP=,crp=,RAL=,st=,MedCacheHub=,codeployed=X,softstate=
2019-11-15 08:59:17.151 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << sap-server: true
2019-11-15 08:59:17.151 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << sap-perf-fesrec: 13762.000000
2019-11-15 08:59:17.151 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << connection: close
2019-11-15 08:59:17.157 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-0: Close connection
2019-11-15 08:59:17.158 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection discarded
2019-11-15 08:59:17.158 DEBUG 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://host:8091][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 100; total allocated: 0 of 200]
2019-11-15 08:59:17.161 ERROR 15276 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.b.h.service.MySalesOrderService        : The endpoint responded with HTTP error code 500.
```

DestinationUtil class

```
public class DestinationUtil {

//  @Value("${destination.http.t4x}")
//  private String destinationName;

    public static HttpDestination getHttpDestinationT4X() {
        Destination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("***");
        return destination.asHttp();
    }

    public static HttpDestination getHttpDestinationS4X() {
        Destination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("***");
        return destination.asHttp();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please check how the outgoing request of the VDM looks like? For this either use the logging configuration described [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html) or use [wiremock in a test environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55458238/3275009). With that you can extract the actual request and check whether it works manually (or what error description is returned).

Comment: I am trying to use wiremock in a test environment. But I got a new issue when running the test case. It failed to get the destination I specified in the code(mandatory in SAP Cloud SDK Version 3).  Actually I already defined the destination as environment variable.

Comment: Then please try the logging approach. And to have a better understanding, please also add the code to your `DestinationUtil.getHttpDestination()` method.

Comment: Could you provide a sample logging configuration for SpringBoot based project generated by archetype scp-cf-spring?

Comment: You would basically need something like this `<logger name="org.apache.http" level="DEBUG"/> <logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="ERROR"/>` in your `application/src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks. I attached the log. Please review.

Comment: Hint: Make sure to omit any confidential or security-relevant information from the traces and code snippets. For instance, I do see cookies in your HTTP log.

Comment: Regarding the actual problem: I see that the SAP S/4HANA backend responds with HTTP 500. Are you aware that the processing on the server failed?

Comment: OK I noticed that you mention that already in your question, so you are apparently aware. The thing is we have to figure out what exactly failed on the server. I propose you consult the error log in transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG.

Comment: I was looking for the system error log but there was nothing to be logged.  Now lack of key information is the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "system error log"? Kindly look in transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG which is titled "SAP Gateway: Error log". Getting a 500 from the server does in most cases result in an error message there.

Comment: Yes, I did as you suggested. But I could not find any error log generated in S/4HANA system.

Comment: Hm, interesting that a 500 doesn't result in a error log entry. Nevertheless, can you please provide the code for your `DestinationUtil.getHttpDestination()`? My feeling is that you haven't wrapped the destination in a `ErpHttpDestination`, causing the `sap-client` and `sap-language` headers to be missing.

Comment: I provided the DestinationUtil java and did some . Actually it works fine for other sdk APIs.

Comment: Hm, as the other calls to the system seem to work (you can see them in your log, the HEAD as well as the $metadata calls succeeded) this seems to be a problem with the system. To clear out the last possible SDK issue, please add `.decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new)` to your DestinationAccessor logic. If it still fails I would advise 1. To double check that no log was written on the system side. 2. Do the failing HTTP request yourself, maybe you can see more then. Maybe the 500 response gives you some more details.

Comment: Or, another idea: can you please adjust your log configuration (the one I provided above) and remove the entry for `org.apache.http.wire`? This will then also print out the body of the requests send, which might give us more ideas on the actual request sent.

Comment: Very sorry about that. I tested the odata service in Postman and got the same error. I should do it earlier. It works fine in sap gateway client. It is not sdk related issue. It is the odata issue.

Comment: Hi Jerry, could you post the payload that provokes the 500 in your post above, pls?

Comment: Hello Emdee, I already posted it originally.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the root cause. It is due to the ICF Nodes configuration of sales order service on S4HANA system. By default, the parameter of GUI configuration is ~CHECK_CSRF_TOKEN 0. That means, xsrf check is disabled and switch to X-Requested-With. I need to provide parameter X-Requested-With in HTTP request header.